# Can all vectors be represented as a list of numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, soft-question, vectors, definition

I've been thinking about vectors, where the common mathematical definition of vectors is that they are elements of a vector space. The most common kind of vector being an element in $\mathbb{F}^n$ which can be represented as a list of $n$ elements(numbers) from $\mathbb{F}$.

For example, polynomials of degree at most $n$ are vectors, and they clearly aren't lists of numbers... but you can encode them as a list of numbers. E.g., $1+2x+x^2$ is $\left[1,2,1\right]$.

Does this apply to every kind of vector?

Comment: No, unless by list of numbers, you allow for infinitely long (and potentially even larger) lists. An example of a vector space like this is $\mathbb R$, which is a vector space with elements of $\mathbb Q$ as the scalars.

Comment: yes, but there are vectors of infinity "entries" of numbers

Answer (score 1):

In a sense, yes.

The basis theorem states that any $F$-vector space can be expressed as a direct sum of copies of $F$, i.e. the form $\bigoplus_{i\in I}F$ where $I$ is some index set.

When the index set is finite, you have your usual set whose elements are "finite lists of numbers" you are talking about. These are just the finite dimensional $F$ vector spaces.

But you have to be aware that $I$ can be any cardinality (for infinite dimensional $F$ spaces) and those can still be thought of as lists of numbers, it's just that they're too long to write. (Also, they necessarily have only finitely many nonzero elements, too. That's important.)